# Insert a logo in a multilingual website - Greek and English

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5

I created the following website which is in Greek and also has an English version. I can change the blue-white logo from the template folder from the *index.php* file. I have also exactly same logo in English version.

I want the Greek version with a Greek logo and the English version with an English logo. I named my logos as *logo2-en-gb.png* and *logo2-gr-gr.png*. Do you know how can I insert it in the *index.php* file?

The website is:

```
http://www.karabatakis.gr
```

and the part in index.php is

```html
<div id="header">
     <div id="companyname" style="height:0%">
        <img style="width:77%"  src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/images/logo2-en-gb.png" />

        <!-- <a href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>"> <?php echo $mainframe->getCfg('sitename') ;?> </a>-->
        <div id="slogan">
           <!-- ΠΟΛΙΤΙΚΟΣ ΜΗΧΑΝΙΚΟΣ -->
        </div>
        <div id="search">
           <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user4" />
        </div>
     </div>
```

I tried something like this, but it does not show me the image:

```html
<img style="width:77%"  src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/images/logo2-".<?php echo $this->language; ?>.".png" />
```

Comment: The PHP code doesn't get executed. That means the file is only read by another php script or the code is in '' and the whole script is PHP code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
if($this->language == 'en') {
    $logo = 'logo2-en-gb.png';
} 
else { 
    $logo = 'logo2-en-gr.png';
}
```

Then...

```
<?php echo $logo; ?>
```

Comment: Just so you know, you can edit your contributions. Just click the edit link after your post.

Comment: What is meant by *"where logo goes echo logo"* (seems incomprehensible)?